# R calculates the average of two cells in a dataframe wrong

Tags: r, average, mean

I need to calculate differences of a particular post and pre shift measurement for one worker and average those two differences. One difference is 9 and the other is -2, but when I use "mean," to calculate the average, R shows 9 and not 4.5. What am I doing wrong. My code(4 and 8 are post, 1 and 5 are pre):

```
   mean((p2res$feno[p2res$no=="4"&p2res$subject.id==4])-
   (p2res$feno[p2res$no=="1"&p2res$subject.id==4])+
   (p2res$feno[p2res$no=="8"&p2res$subject.id==4])-
   (p2res$feno[p2res$no=="5"&p2res$subject.id==4])) 

    p2res <- structure(list(subject.id = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), no = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 6, 7, 8), feno = c(24, 23, 40, 35, 28, 25, 22, 26, 19, 19, 18, 
    19, 15, 14, 29, 18)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = 
    c("data.frame"))

      subject.id  no  feno
               4  1   24
               4  2   23
               4  3   40
               4  4   35
               4  5   28
               4  6   25
               4  7   22
               4  8   26
               6  1   19
               6  2   19
               6  3   18
               6  4   19
               6  5   15
               6  6   14
               6  7   29
               6  8   18
```

Also, How can I make a function to do this for other measurements?

Comment: Can you share your data with `dput(p2res)`?

Comment: x <- structure(list(subject.id = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 
        6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), no = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
        6, 7, 8), feno = c(24, 23, 40, 35, 28, 25, 22, 26, 19, 19, 18, 
        19, 15, 14, 29, 18)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", 
        "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: I'm not sure how to show you the data.frame, but that's what I got from dput()

Comment: @Nilou that's the data frame, anyone can copy/paste it into R now.

Comment: @Gregor Thank you! I'm new to stack overflow and somewhat new to R too.

Comment: If you run each piece of your code, each of your subsets returns a single value. `p2res$feno[p2res$no=="4"&p2res$subject.id==4]` is 35, the next one is 24, then 26, then 28. So, inside `mean` you have `35 - 24 + 26 - 28`, which is `9`. So you ask for `mean(9)`, and you get `9` as the result.

Comment: If you want the mean of `35 - 24` and `26 - 28`, then you shouldn't add them together, instead you need to concatenate them in a vector: `mean(c(35 - 24, 26- 28))`, or in pulling from the data `mean(c(p2res$feno[p2res$no=="4"&p2res$subject.id==4] - p2res$feno[p2res$no=="1"&p2res$subject.id==4], p2res$feno[p2res$no=="8"&p2res$subject.id==4] - p2res$feno[p2res$no=="5"&p2res$subject.id==4]))`

Comment: @Nilou You can [edit] your post by clicking the edit button below the tags. When you have clarifying information or data, you should edit your question and paste it in. Comments don't last forever and it's impossible to read code or data that's put in a comment

Answer (score 1):

This is because R is interpreting your code is not formatted correctly for input into `mean`, given that  <s>`mean` can only evaluate numeric or logical vectors.</s> you are evaluating the expression before you are calculating the mean, ie. you are calculating the mean of 9, resulting in 9.

Additionally, 35-24 returns 11, whereas 26-28 returns -2. Perhaps there was a different value you are referring about? So the average of 11 and -2 is 4.5, so assuming you meant to put 11 not 9.

What you could do (if you dont want to write a function) do is define a variable of length 2.
`x<-c(((p2res$feno[p2res$no=="4"&p2res$subject.id==4])-(p2res$feno[p2res$no=="1"&p2res$subject.id==4])), ((p2res$feno[p2res$no=="8"&p2res$subject.id==4])-(p2res$feno[p2res$no=="5"&p2res$subject.id==4])))`

Then,

`mean(x)`

Gives 4.5

Comment: Can you help with writing a function for this?

Comment: I dont know how helpful this will be...


 `myfunction<-function(x){
 
 num<- nrow(p2res)

 id<-(p2res$feno[p2res$no=="4"&p2res$subject.id==4])
 id2<-(p2res$feno[p2res$no=="1"&p2res$subject.id==4])
 id3<-(p2res$feno[p2res$no=="8"&p2res$subject.id==4])
 id4<-(p2res$feno[p2res$no=="5"&p2res$subject.id==4])

 num1<-id-id2
 num2<-id3-id4

 getmean<-c(num1,num2)

    return(mean(getmean))}

myfunction(x) `


I am not sure what overall pattern you are looking for. Are you looking for a function that returns the mean of every possible pair subtracting every other possible pair?

Answer (score 0):

You can produce something that is more readable and easier to work with by using `subset` to extract the data for subject.id 4.

```
subj4 <- subset(p2res, subject.id==4)
mean(c(subj4$feno[4]-subj4$feno[1], subj4$feno[8]-subj4$feno[5]))
```

Using `attach` for `subj4` allows R to find the variable without adding the `subj4` variable name. This increases readability further.

```
subj4 <- subset(p2res, subject.id==4)
attach(subj4)
mean(c(feno[4]-feno[1], feno[8]-feno[5]))
```

Use `detach(subj4)` to undo this, if you wish.

Comment: I knew my code is not the most sophisticated one, but I didn't know how to make it better. I do have many subjects. This definitely help with readability. Thank you!

Comment: You can also do this with the `dplyr` package to extract all the subjects' values. `library(dplyr); p2res %>% group_by(subject.id) %>% summarize(mean(c(feno[4]-feno[1],feno[8]-feno[5])))`. This will give you an object with all the desired calculations by `subject.id`.